# How to use selectively choose the lambda version for an APIG API at runtime?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case where an API backed by a lambda has to be latency critical for a few clients but there are clients how call the API with high volume in bursts and the latency restrictions are liberal .

We are using provisioned concurrency for the latency critical calls and do not want to use it for non latency critical calls as the cost is high.

Since provisioned concurrency can only be used with alias/version, is it possible to choose the lambda version at runtime based on the API Key?

Determine the client based on the API Key and point to the appropriate version. I am trying to avoid creating 2 API endpoints one for latency critical clients and the other for non-latency critical clients.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for API Gateway to invoke a Lambda function alias based on the API key passed in the request. What you can do is set up 2 API Gateway [stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html), one for latency critical calls and the other for non-critical ones. Now, the Lambda function integration would need to be set up to use API GW stage variables so the appropriate Lambda function alias can be invoked based on the stage. You can refer to this blog post on how to configure that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html

So, using this method, you would be creating two endpoints, but the API configuration for both would be similar.

Comment: I tried the stages approach and it works. The only problem is that I am using serverless cloudformation and unable to deploy 2 stages of the same API. Do you know how to do it using serverless cloudformation?